# Fixing dishwasher tray that has loosened

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Maytag dishwasher whose upper tray has come loose off the rail. Attaching a pic that describes the issue. Would be great to get any tips.

[image]

Comment: They are meant to be removable..just place it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the plastic moving parts of a dishwasher wear over time, or become less springy. Generally you can pop wheels/sliders back on, and reinsert them in the runners if necessary, but if it keeps happening, you may need to track down spares. I've had to replace a set of wheels on my zanussi in the past.

If it won't go back together because a bit had broken off, see if there's a scrap of plastic in the filters, to identify which part has broken, or inspect and carefully try to unclip the opposite one.